# How to template a stack allocated array of polymorphic pointers to interfaces, including the corresponding pointee of derived type?

Tags: c++, embedded, c++14

For context, I am working on an embedded high reliability environment. Some of the restrictions put in place in this environment include;

1. No dynamic memory allocation
2. Compliance with c++14 or lower is required
3. No run time type information

So the end result is that I want a class containing an `const std::array` of pointers of type BaseInterface, that can contain a stack allocated set of arbitrary Derived classes.

Consider the non-complete example below.

**Note:** BaseHandler constructor, and member variable comments for more contextual questions.

```
#include <array>
#include <tuple>
class BaseInterface {
 public:
  virtual void DoSomething() = 0;
};

class Derived1 : public BaseInterface {
  void DoSomething() override {}
};
class Derived2 : public BaseInterface {
  void DoSomething() override {}
};

/**
 * @brief Handles stack allocated polymorphic arrays
 *
 * @tparam base_ptr_t pointer type that each element must derive from
 * @tparam derived_t parameter pack of derived variables
 */
template <class base_ptr_t, class... derived_t>
class BaseHandler {
 public:
  BaseHandler(Elements &&... element)
      : memory_store_x_{std::forward<derived_t>(element)...},
        array_(/* How to make each elementwise pointer point to each element in the tuple/array of aligned_union?*/) {}
  typedef std::array<base_ptr_t, sizeof...(Elements)> array_t;

  const array_t GetArray();

 private:
  const array_t array_;
  // Use tuple to store actual memory?
  const std::tuple<Elements...> memory_store_0_;
  // Use array of aligned_union's to store (perhaps memory inneficient compared
  // to tuple) ??
  std::array<std::aligned_union_t<0, derived_t...>, sizeof...(derived_t)>
      memory_store_1_;
};

template <size_t N>
void Foo(const std::array<const BaseInterface *, N> &arr) {
  // Do something interesting
}

int main() {
  // Intended usage
  BaseHandler<const BaseInterface *, Derived1, Derived2> handler(Derived1(),
                                                                 Derived2());

  auto arr = handler.GetArray();
  Foo(arr);
}
```

Some of the workarounds that I explored and did not like include;

1. Creating a functional non-generic helper class/function containing `static const std::array<X,X>` e.g.

```cpp
const std::array<BaseInterface*,2> MakeResourceList() {
 // Static lifetime, i.e. will not be destroyed when out of scope
 static const Derived1 a();
 static const Derived2 b();
 std::array<BaseInterface*,2> result = {&a,&b};
 return result;
}
```

2. Constructing all resources and manually passing them into an array. Leads to code bloat.
3. Using global variables for all constructed resources.

Comment: It seems strange to me that C++ is allowed in such an environment, let alone C++11. All industry standards worth mentioning demand a safe subset of the language to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to store the derived objects as a tuple, then apply that tuple with a function that converts this into an array:

```
template <class base_t, class... derived_t>
class BaseHandler {
    static_assert(std::conjunction_v<std::is_base_of_v<base_t, derived_t>...>);
    std::tuple<derived_t...> storage_;

public:
    std::array<base_t*, sizeof...(derived_t)> GetArray() {
        return std::apply([](derived_t&... deriveds){
            return std:array<base_t*, sizeof...(derived_t)>{{&deriveds...}};
        }, storage_);
    }
};
```

This uses C++17 for a few library things for clarity, but all of them can be implemented in C++14 with no issues.

I also changed the template parameter from `base_ptr_t` to `base_t` since it makes all your template parameters the same "kind", and you don't have to do `remove_pointer_t` in the static assertion.